# Shared_ptr instance is not set for an object as expected

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, shared-ptr

I have a struct A which has a member another struct C. So A with c1Ptr_ as member.
I use 2 structs S and N. N has as member A, a_  and S has as member C, c_.
After I instantiated A and create for S a c object using the created A object and I pass the created A object to N I would expect to have the A->c1Ptr_ in N as well.
Thank you.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    
    struct C1 
    {
        C1(int x):x_(x)
        {
            std::cout<<"-C1: x_: " << x_ << std::endl;
        }
        int x_;
        ~C1()
        {
            std::cout<<"-DC1: x_: " << x_ << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    using C1ptr = std::shared_ptr<C1>;
    
    
    
    struct A
    {
       C1ptr c1Ptr;
    };
    
    
    struct S
    {
       S(C1ptr& c1Ptr):c1Ptr_(c1Ptr)
       {
           
       }
       
       C1ptr c1Ptr_;
    };
    
    struct N
    { 
        N(std::shared_ptr<A> a):a_(a)
        {
            
        }
        std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
    };
    
    
    
    int main()
    {
       std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
       S s(a->c1Ptr);
       N n(a);
       
       s.c1Ptr_ = std::make_shared<C1>(12);
       
       if (n.a_->c1Ptr)
       {
           std::cout<<"c1Ptr is set for N\n";
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout<<"c1Ptr is NOT set for N\n"; // why c1Ptr is not set for n.a_ ? 
       }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Copied null shared_ptrs are not connected to each other. If you assign something to one, others won't change.

Comment: More descriptive names would make your code much easier to understand

Comment: Replace `C1ptr` with type `int`. Do you see your problem now?

Comment: I dont need int I need a struct.

Comment: @DeanLi you need to understand how it works first. Replace type `C1ptr` and look into your code. If you change `int` in one structure would you expect another `int` from another structure magically change as well? If not why do you expect that from a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Just after `s.c1Ptr_ = make_shared<C1>(12);` add this line: `n.a_->c1Ptr = s.c1Ptr_;`

Comment: Change the `std::shared_ptr` to raw pointers in your code, and see if this becomes less confusing.  Assigning a new value to a pointer does not change other variables that happened to hold the old pointer.

Comment: *"After I instantiated A and create for S a c object using the created A object"* -- I don't see the "using the created A object" demonstrated in your code. Your code creates a c object using `12`. How do you figure that `a` is present in the line `s.c1Ptr_ = std::make_shared<C1>(12);`?

Comment: *"After I instantiated A and create for S a c object using the created A object and I pass the created A object to N"* -- the order of events in your code has "pass the created A object to N" before "create for S a c object". I think this does not affect the outcome (although it is a bit confusing trying to follow the arbitrary, one-letter names), but this is the sort of detail that could be important. *Yes, I have pointed out several seemingly minor details like this. The idea is that if you learn to describe your issue precisely, you might start to see an answer as you write your question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to work this out on your own by drawing the objects `a`, `s`, and `n` and their contents, and what their contents point to:

> ```
> auto a = std::make_shared<A>();  // a(c1Ptr_ = null)
> S s(a->c1Ptr_);                  // a(c1Ptr_ = null), s(c1Ptr_ = null)
> N n(a);                          // a(c1Ptr_ = null), s(c1Ptr_ = null), n(a_ = a)
>                                  // [n.a_ points to a]
> ```

After this initial block of instructions:

- `a` and `s` have their shared pointer members `c1Ptr_` with a value of nullptr.
- `n` has its shared pointer member `a_` pointing to the object `a`.

> ```
> s.c1Ptr_ = std::make_shared<C1>(12);  // (1) a(c1Ptr_ = null), s(c1Ptr_->x_ = 12 ), n(a_ = a) 
>                                       //     [and you modify s]
> if (n.a_->c1Ptr_) {
>     std::cout << "c1Ptr is set for N\n\n";
> }
> else {
>     std::cout << "c1Ptr is NOT set for N\n\n";  // (1)
> }
> ```

Here:

- you just modify `s.c1Ptr_`, but that doesn't affect `a`, and ultimately, `n`.
- `s.c1Ptr_` was originally set to point to the same `C1` object as `a.c1Ptr_` (actually, nullptr); now you're just making it point to something else.

> ```
> a->c1Ptr_ = std::make_shared<C1>(15);  // (2) a(c1Ptr_->x_ = 15 ), s(c1Ptr_->x_ = 12 ), n(a_ = a)
>                                        //     [and you modify a]
> if (n.a_->c1Ptr_) {
>     std::cout << "c1Ptr is set for N\n\n";  // (2)
> }
> else {
>     std::cout << "c1Ptr is NOT set for N\n\n";
> }
> ```

What would have happened if you had changed `a->c1Ptr_` instead? Since `n->a_` points to `a` and we are modifying `a`, `n->a_->c1Ptr_` is also set.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/TeadebjKq)

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` doesn't share a pointer, it shares ownership of a pointer.

This means that you can change individual `shared_ptr` to point to other things, indepnendent of other `shared_ptr`'s, but as soon as there's no `shared_ptr` pointing at something, that something get's deleted. Think of it as adding a counter to the pointer. When you create, delete or reassign a `shared_ptr` to something other than nullptr, you will increment or decrement the counter. If the counter reaches 0 (usually on a delete) then it also deletes the pointer.

In your case you are copying a nullptr from a. So you have two `shared_ptr` both storing nullptr. Then you change one of them to point to a new thing (12). This won't change anything else in memory, or specifically the value of other `shared_ptr`s.